# How I Can track customers around in my magento store

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to track the customer event what they are doing on website and current link of customer ip location etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visitor activity you can use  Google Analytics but you cant get customer IP .

other all the information you get in the google analitics

you cant get IP because it against GDPR.

Comment: there is any magento extesion which show the same result on backend

Comment: no any extension

Comment: anyother way then google analytics

Answer (score 0):

**You can use also use Criteo for Analytics.**

In Criteo you can also send custom Parameters, As well as you can also track Home, Cart, Checkout, PDP (Product Description Page), PLP (Product Listing Page) etc.

Once Try Criteo, This is good for E-Commerce.

**Link: https://www.criteo.com/**